# Create an Azure SQL DB from an external mssql backup file

Tags: sql, azure, backup

I have a backup file of an mssql database using which I would like to create a database in Azure SQL.I see option for restoring a database in azure. But I dont find an option to create a database in Azure SQL from an external backup file.kindly advise.

Answer (score 2):

The data import steps might not be same as how we restore an on premise sql database.
The Data can easily be  restored from a azure backup in azure portal ( just import it into a new sql db).

For migrating an on-premise sql database to azure sql database Microsoft provides a tool DMA (Data Migration Assistant). This tool provides a wizard based step by step approach to connect to your on-premise sql database source , select the objects to migrate , generate a script , follow the migration progress and errors if any during the process.

A few changes might be required post migration in the Azure sql database to update the  pricing tier , performance and compatibility level.

Here is a  document demonstrating a step by step process to migrate an on-premise sql database to azure sql database -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-migrate-your-sql-server-database